# Figurative meaning of 結果的に 「一直線で来られてよかった」?

Tags: translation, meaning

I came across this sentence:

> 「結果的に **一直線で来られて**よかった」

The sentence was uttered after the character reached the place where he wanted to go. Why I don't think that this statement is used in a literal sense is because he had to take an alternative route to come there (he couldn't walk straight to where he wanted to be).

Especially the 「結果的に」 seems to me as if the  「**一直線で来られて**」is used figuratively.

In any case, I haven't found any senteces that use this construction in a similar way.

So my question is whether I am in the right with regarding this construction as 'metaphorical' or if I am missing the point here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a weird metaphor here. This sentence means the "alternative route", which he had avoided at first, turned out to be the straight (and thus better) route. Please read the previous sentences carefully again.

> 結果的に一直線で来られてよかった。
>   As it turned out, I was able to come here straight (and that was good).